# Online project management tool that does not store personal information

Tags: trello, privacy

Since trello keeps logs of ip addresses ([Does Trello keep logs of IP addresses every time someone signs in an account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111358/does-trello-keep-logs-of-ip-addresses-every-time-someone-signs-in-an-account/111362#111362)), I searched for an alternative project management tool that does not but it seems that all of them have the same privacy policy. 
So, is there an online project management tool that does not store such data or should I switch to a self-hosted solution?

Answer (score 1):

Some companies claim to regularly wipe their logs (e.g., DuckDuckGo), but there's no way to be sure what a website does with its server logs unless you control the site yourself. So if you don't want your IP address logged by a project-management site, you need to run your own software or hide your IP address with e.g. Tor.